# Flex page-layout not working in IE11 - flex grow not playing nice

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to set up a simple page layout using flex but cannot seem to get it to work in IE11. The main component refuses to grow to fill the space like it does in Chrome or Safari. I've read everything I can find about flex-grow on IE but to no avail.

```css
    html, body {
     width: 100vw;
     min-height: 100vh;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    body {
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
     background: black;
    }
    header {
     background: pink;
     height: 100px;
    }
    main {
     background: lightgrey;
     -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
     -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     height: 100%;
    }
    footer {
     background: lightblue;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
     -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#"><span>Privacy</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#"><span>Sitemap</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#"><span>Newsletter</span></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </header>
 <main>
  The main Section
 </main>
 <footer>
  Footer
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give,

```
height:100%; for html and body
```

and need to remove

```
height: 100%  from main
```

Comment: But of course!! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @SChalk did it work on your system... Its working with mine..

Comment: Seems to be working like a charm on IE11, Safari, and Chrome :)